# uniq by only a part of the line

Tags: email, awk, uniq

I am trying to consolidate an email list, but I want to `uniq` (or `uniq -i -u`) by the email address, not the entire line so that we don't have duplicates.

list 1:

```
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
```

list 2:

```
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
Fake Person <companyb@companyb.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
```

the current output is

```
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
Fake Person <companyb@companyb.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
```

the desired output would be

```
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
```

(as `companyb@companyb.com` is listed in both)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z.]+/) {      # look for emailish string *
    a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]=$0   # and hash the record using the address as key
}
END {                                 # after all are processed
    for(i in a)                       # output them in no particular order
        print a[i]
}' file2 file1                        # switch order to see how it affects output
```

Output

```
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
```

Script looks for very simple emailish string (* see the regex in the script and tune it to your liking) which it uses to hash the whole records,last instance wins as the earlier onse are overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

given your file format

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' '!a[$2]++' files
```

will print the first instance of duplicate content in angled brackets.  Or if there is no content after the email, you don't need to un-wrap the angled brackets

```
$ awk '!a[$NF]++' files
```

Same can be done with `sort` as well

```
$ sort -t'<' -k2,2 -u files
```

side-effect is output will be sorted which can be desired (or not).

**N.B.** For both alternatives the assumption is angled brackets don't appear anywhere else than the email wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

`uniq` has an `-f` option to ignore a number of blank-delimited fields, so we can sort on the third field and then ignore the first two:

```
$ sort -k 3,3 infile | uniq -f 2
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
```

However, this isn't very robust: it breaks as soon as there aren't exactly two fields before the email address as the sorting will be on the wrong field and `uniq` will compare the wrong fields.

<sub>Check karakfa's answer to see how `uniq` isn't even required here.</sub>

Alternatively, just checking for uniqueness of the last field:

```
awk '!e[$NF] {print; ++e[$NF]}' infile
```

<sub>or even shorter, stealing from karakfa, `awk '!e[$NF]++' infile`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
   match($0,/<.*>/)
   val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
FNR==NR{
   a[val]=$0
   print
   next
}
!(val in a)
' list1 list2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program here.
{                                        ##Starting BLOCK which will be executed for both of the Input_files.
   match($0,/<.*>/)                      ##Using match function of awk where giving regex to match everything from < to till >
   val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)         ##Creating variable named val whose value is substring of current line starting from RSTART to value of RLENGTH, basically matched string.
}                                        ##Closing above BLOCK here.
FNR==NR{                                 ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file named list1 will be read.
   a[val]=$0                             ##Creating an array named a whose index is val and value is current line.
   print $0                              ##Printing current line here.
   next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!(val in a)                              ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT present in array a if it is NOT present then do printing of current line.
' list1 list2                            ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Company A <companya@companya.com>
Company B <companyb@companyb.com>
Company C <companyc@companyc.com>
firstname lastname <firstname@gmail.com>
Joe lastnanme <joe@gmail.com>
```

Comment: Yeah, using `<..>` is smarter. Probably in some RFC too.

Comment: @JamesBrown, thank you sir :) your encouragement, it made  my day honestly :)

Comment: Very well explained solution ++

Comment: @anubhava, thanks a TON abubhava sir for encouragement, this is great day for me  having encouragement from 2 geeks on SO. Really thankful to GOD:)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand the question !
but you can try this awk :

```
awk 'NR!=FNR && $3 in a{next}{a[$3]}1' list1 list2
```